# Spring Data Rest Does Not Update Default Value in DB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a Spring Boot application using Spring Data REST. I have a domain entity called User with a boolean field isTeacher.  This field has been already setup by our DBA in the User table with type bit and a default value of 1:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;  // This Id has been setup as auto generated in DB

    @Column(name = "IS_TEACHER")
    private boolean isTeacher;
```

}

And the User repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

I was able to add a new user by giving the below request and POST to http://localhost:8080/users, a new user was created in the DB having isTeacher value 1:

```
{ 
    "isTeacher" : true
}
```

However, when I tried to change IS_TEACHER by giving PATCH (or PUT) and this request:

```
{ 
    "isTeacher" : false
}
```

The response showed that "isTeacher" is still true and the value didn't get changed in the table either.  Can someone please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: I think this create new entry right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to `@Data` annotation of `lombok` is ignoring if you have a field that start with `isXx` it generates getters and setters to boolean with isTeacher for getters and setTeacher for setters then you are not able to update correctly your property, if you put `"teacher"` when updating should work but you should solve this by overriding that setter.

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE) private boolean isTeacher;

public void setIsTeacher(boolean isTeacher) {
    this.isTeacher = isTeacher;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Changing it to "teacher" did solve my problem without overriding the setter (I will add the new setter later).  To simplify the issue, I didn't mention that I have another boolean field called "active" without the prefix "is" in the name.  However, the "teacher" worked now but the "active" field still can't be updated.  Any idea why?  Thanks

Comment: I'm now sure which is that field you refer, could you post that new field? Or create another question so that I can help you :)

Comment: I have updated the post above with the new field.  Please help. Thank you.

Comment: I changed the variable name of "active" and now it's working.  I don't know why

Comment: Hi @jip Perhaps, `rebuild` solved your problems that are general issues when using `lombok` because the IDE sometimes ignores them in runtime execution.